# I am unable to create a project using XTRF

Tags: xtrf

I am unable to create a project with some languages. For example I have selected Russian as target language and tries to create a project using 'createProject' XTRF Webservice API , but I am getting the following error. I am able to create a estimate using the same value with XTRF REST API calls.

UnknownEntityNameFaultException: Unknown entity name, type=com.radzisz.xtrf.model.dictionary.Language, name=ru

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Regards,
Vamsi Grandhi

Answer (score 0):

The system will look for this language code in column "ISO 639-1 Code".
Language has to be defined in the system.

If the language cannot be found on the list, it will cause an error as in the given case (no language 'ru').

Please check ru-RU (vide en-US and en-GB).

Kind regards,
XTRF Team